# how to select from a dataframe into a list where the length of the string is a certain size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I finally gave up finding a nice compact pandas answer and did this:

```
states_list = self.activities_df["park_states"].unique()
for state in states_list:
    if len(state) == 2:
        distinct_states.append(state)
```

All the other ways I tried to do this with pandas didn't work. I tried this type of logic:

```
states_list = df[df.column_name.str.len() == 2]
distinct_states = states_list['column_name']
```

I tried this type of logic:

```
list = df[(df['col_1'].str.len() == 2)]
```

I've tried multiple other things and many different combinations of the above, and I can't get it the syntax correct.

What's the best way to do what I'm wanting using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.loc` :

```
my_list = df.loc[df['col_1'].str.len() == 2, 'col_1'].values.tolist()
```

#### For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['a','ab','ac','abc','acb','ad']})

length_to_find = 2
my_list = df.loc[df['col_1'].str.len() == length_to_find, 'col_1'].values.tolist()

print(my_list)
```

#### Output:

```
['ab', 'ac', 'ad']
```

#### Note:

Depending on the contents of the column, you may need to convert the column type to a **string** before extracting the list, otherwise you may end up with errors.

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].astype('str')
```

Comment: Thanks. As written, the first worked, but there were duplicates in the dataframe. I was able to add .unique() to unduplicate.
`distinct_states = self.activities_df.loc[self.activities_df["park_states"].str.len() == length_to_find,"park_states"].unique()`

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as a listcomp if statement with the following syntax `my_variable = [x for x in iterable if condition]`:

`distinct_states= [state for state in self.activities_df["park_states"].unique() if len(state) == 2]`

But since I don't have more information that's the best I could come up with.

If you provide more data in your question, I'm sure we could figure it out.

Comment: Don't use list comprehension for side effects. Here `sates_list` will be a list of `None`.

Comment: I updated it to reflect my original intent. I suppose I was a bit distracted and siding realize my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.